# Why is the md5 checksum of a symbolic link is equal to the original file

Tags: linux, md5sum

I have been looking for a while, and I cannot fathom why the md5 checksum of a symbolic link equals to the file it points to. In my understanding [a symbolic link is still a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). Given that it is empty I would expect a symlink to have an md5 of d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10910079/4121573))

However testing in practice:

```
echo Hello World > test
ln -s test test_symlink
```

Then running:

```
md5deep test test_symlink
```

Yields:

```
e59ff97941044f85df5297e1c302d260  /tmp/test
e59ff97941044f85df5297e1c302d260  /tmp/test_symlink
```

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Comment: The whole *point* of a symbolic link is to be usable as a transparent *pointer* to the destination - i.e. that you can operate on it just the same as if you had operated on the target (opening and reading data, checking metadata, etc). There are calls that can identify symbolic links and tools like `ls` use them. The `md5deep` tool evidently hasn't bothered, probably because nobody is interested in that.

Comment: The same reason that `cat test` and `cat test_symlink` print the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A symbolic link is transparent to *almost all* filesystem operations; that's the point of it. When you `open` a symlink, it actually opens the target file, and it's the contents of the target file that get MD5'd. Only `readlink` and `lstat` (and the much more rarely used `lchown`, `lutimes`, and `open(..., O_PATH|O_NOFOLLOW)`) are able to "see" a symlink instead of the file behind it.

Comment: I saw the md5s being equal indeed. Actually I should have realize the tool does not take into account the nature of a symlink as deleting the target file, and trying to compute the md5 on the broken link yields `md5sum: test_symlink: No such file or directory`. Thanks for the explanation.